# How to crop view with mask, but leave cropped-out parts partially opaque instead of hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, mask, alpha

I want to crop out a portion of a view. I followed this article: ["How to mask one UIView using another UIView"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-mask-one-uiview-using-another-uiview), and this is my code currently:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        /// show a green border around the image view's original frame
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 300))
        backgroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 4
        view.addSubview(backgroundView)
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 300))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "TestImage")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        // MARK: - Mask code
        let maskView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        maskView.backgroundColor = .blue /// ensure opaque
        view.addSubview(maskView)
        
        imageView.mask = maskView
        
    }
}
```

The mask is working fine:

| Without mask | With mask |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Full image with no cropping] | [image: Only a small square of image visible, the rest is cropped out. A green border indicates the original, uncropped image's frame.] |

However, I want the parts of the image view that are cropped out to still be there, but just have a lower alpha. This is what it should look like:

[image: Full image with cropping, but the parts that are cropped out are still there. They just have a lower alpha.]

I've tried changing `maskView.alpha` to `0.25`, but that just makes the part with the mask be less opaque.

[image: Cropped image that has 0.25 alpha]

How can I make the cropped-out parts **still be there**, but just a bit more transparent?

Preferably I don't want to make another view, because eventually I'll be using this on a camera preview layer — an extra view might have a cost on performance.

---

Edit: [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66619413/14351818)

I tried adding a subview with a background color with less alpha:

```
let maskView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300))
maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

let maskView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
maskView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(1)
maskView2.alpha = 0

maskView.addSubview(maskView2)

imageView.mask = maskView
```

But this is the result:

[image: Entire image has 0.3 alpha]

Comment: Alpha blending with white is the same thing as screen. If screen is what you want, specify! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s all in the transparency of the colors you paint the mask with. (The hues — what we usually think of as color — are irrelevant.) The masking depends upon the degree of transparency. Areas of the mask that are partially transparent will make the masked view be partially transparent.

So make the mask the whole size of the target view, and make the whole mask a partially transparent color, except for the central area which is an opaque color.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So should I add an opaque subview to the masking view?

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Do you know how I can make it partially transparent?

Comment: That's what my answer tells you. Added a screen shot showing that what I said to do achieves the desired result.

Comment: That is perfect! But I still don't know how to change the degree of transparency, in parts of the mask. Is it by setting a different `backgroundColor`?

Comment: Sure, if the mask is a view and its subview, that's a simple easy way.

Comment: I tried using `withAlphaComponent(0.3)` on the mask view and `withAlphaComponent(1)` on the subview, but the entire image just turned less opaque - the area with the full alpha was the same. If you can, can you post the code for what you did in your answer?

Comment: Delete `maskView2.alpha = 0`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!